# Shutdown whole network computers

Tags: windows, windows-xp, shutdown, remote, remote-control

Imagine you have network with about 70 computers which work with none-administrator users. What I need is to shutdown whole network or group of computers at once from one computer. I actually found (!NOT TESTED! don't know if it really works or not) some paid software called [Remote Computer Manager](http://www.mylanviewer.com/remote-computer.html) after research. The questions are

1. Is there any free/opensource software that can do what I want to do even to none-admin users without any client software (using windows inbuilt functionality etc..)?
2. WHat do you think about Remote Computer Manager? Is it reliable?

Please tell me both clientless and with client, free solutions that can do this job.

All pc's are using windows XP

Answer (score 6):

Since you are networked, you could make a batch script with all the computer names to run the built in Windows command.

`shutdown -m \\COMPUTERNAME -f -t 00`

That sends the shutdown command with the following switches:

- -m requires the "\IDENTIFIER", so that could be IP or computer name
- Add -r if you want reboot, -s for shutdown
- -f Forces running applications to close without prompting the user
- -t is a definition of timing in seconds.  so 00 means now.

I just tested it in my small network of 5 and it worked on them all. (Edit: We have XP and 7, so I feel confident to say it'll work on any DOS box since XP).

Comment: Keep in mind, other network PC's is running under restricted user, not admin. and I got on some other network  (not the one that I'm talking about) `Access denied` error. And please give me solution for all computers of, say 192.168.40.xx network. Not for one

Comment: read my comment, and make edits for batch shutdowning not only 1 pc

Comment: @user978733 Like I said, incorporate it into a batch script.  Something like `for /L %%x in (1, 1, 255) do shutdown -m 192.168.40.%%x -s -f -t 00`  You may need to do some of your own footwork.  Assuming you have authority to act on the machines, you may need to go enable net shutdown on the boxes (which may require you to have a domain account with the privileges.  If you are in the place with this need and 70pcs, you should have that anyway.  Another option is to use [PsShutdown](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897541) and provide credentials to do so.

Comment: Where's the name/IP address list?

Comment: It loops in `(1, 1, 255)` and is populated in the `%%x` at the end of the `192.168.40.%%x`.  The loop in batch is `(start, step, end)` - so that example does 1-255.  You can see more [here](http://ss64.com/nt/for_l.html).

Comment: `you may need to go enable net shutdown on the boxes` - how?

Comment: Two things: 1) If you want a GUI and to list all PCs on your own - try `shutdown -i`, it'll give you a pop-up with options.  2) [Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/539.mspx?mfr=true) Provides a good resource there.  Now I have given you all the tools, so with some of your own leg-work you can get where you want to be.  Easiest option for you, just be a domain admin.  Otherwise, you'll have to config all of those PCs.  Good luck!