# Force shutdown from a remote system

Tags: windows, windows-xp, command-line, batch, group-policy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Shutdown whole network computers](https://superuser.com/questions/514633/shutdown-whole-network-computers)

What I want to do is to allow EVERYONE `Force shutdown from a remote system` control.

[image]

But, I don't want to do this manually because count of pc's is really big. Is there any way to do this via batch script on windows XP?

Comment: Are these systems in an Active Directory domain?  If so, what server version?

Comment: I think this will get closed as off-topic per the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq), it's specific to corporate IT and networks.  Might be better to go to [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/)?

Comment: @DaveM The only thing that I need to do is to set everyone into this option via bat script

Comment: Why not just use the Group Policies you're looking at?

Comment: @techie007 as I posted in my question `because count of pc's is really big. ` I can't do it one by one in all pc's. I need 1 click batch script

Comment: Group Policies are intended for applying policies to many computers in a domain network (without visiting each of them).  Are your computers in an Active Directory domain?  If so, then you setup the GP at the server and have it apply to the computers in the domain (or OU, etc.).

Comment: +1 to all the above recommending Active Directory.  Also, I'd generally recommend against using the Everyone group.  If you *must* make the permissions anywhere near so broad, try using Authenticated Users instead.